# Using wildcard operator in quotes in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to set a before filter in a rails app as follows:

```
before_filter :set_instance_variables, :unless => :active_pages?

def active_pages?
  params[:controller] == "admin/*"
end
```

where I would like it to have the * represent any word so that the method is checking against any of the controllers that start with 'admin/'.  I thought the asterisk might be a wild card and work, but it doesn't seem to be working.  How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
def active_pages?
  %r{^admin/.*} =~ params[:controller]
end
```

It uses `=~` to match a String to a regular expression, and `%r{}` for the regular expression because your pattern contains a `/` (the `//` notation would be harder to read).

Comment: +1, but having the regex first feels like Yoda conditions to me ;-)

Answer (score 1):

There are several solutions to this problem. From my point of view, the simplest solution without involving regular expressions is [`String#index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-index)

```
def active_pages?
  params[:controller].index("admin/") == 0
end
```

The other solution is a regular expression, as other users already suggested.

```
def active_pages?
  params[:controller] =~ %r{^admin/.*}
end
```

I personally prefer the `index` solution in this case. As a bonus, `index` appears to be a little bit faster (actually the difference is not very noticeable) than the regular expression.

Here's a benchmark.

```
require 'benchmark'

array = (1..1000000).map { "string#{rand(4)}/string" }

Benchmark.bmbm do |x|
  x.report("index") { array.each { |item| item.index("string2") == 0 } }
  x.report("regex")  { array.each { |item| item =~ %r{^string2/.*} } }
end
```

And here's the result.

```
$ ruby index.rb 
Rehearsal -----------------------------------------
index   0.560000   0.020000   0.580000 (  0.582749)
regex   1.000000   0.020000   1.020000 (  1.015548)
-------------------------------- total: 1.600000sec

            user     system      total        real
index   0.570000   0.000000   0.570000 (  0.576076)
regex   0.970000   0.020000   0.990000 (  0.988980)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use some regular expressions

```
def active_pages?
    params[:controller] =~ /^admin\/\w+$/
end
```